# Are actions allowed in MVVM? Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, mvvm, action

If MVVM is all about data binding and cannot do something like `view.doThis()`, otherwise it's MVP, then how to invoke actions on views?

Suppose I have view that has a `snackbar`. `View` is controlled by its `ViewModel`. How is this `ViewModel` supposed to show `snackbar` without going `snackbar.show()`?

Answer (score 7):

In MVVM, ViewModel captures the state of the view. View observes the ViewModel for changes and updates itself. Thus, the communication between View & ViewModel happens through change of values (as against method calls in MVP).

Since `Snackbar` is like a global behaviour (like Toast), it can be implemented at the Activity/Fragment level. So, you can make a `MessageHelper` interface and pass it to the ViewModel as a dependency. Activity will implement it and display `Snackbar`.

Example:

- [ItemViewModel that consumes the interface](https://github.com/manas-chaudhari/android-mvvm/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/manaschaudhari/android_mvvm/sample/ItemViewModel.java)
- [Activity base class that implements the interface](https://github.com/manas-chaudhari/android-mvvm/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/manaschaudhari/android_mvvm/sample/BaseActivity.java)

However, its possible that there is some view specific behaviour which cannot be implemented at the Activity level. For such cases, you can make use of `databinding.Observable` to trigger an event. For example, lets say we want to animate a particular view. We can create a BindingAdapter

```
@BindingAdapter({"shakeTrigger"})
public static void showSnackbar(View view, Void trigger) {
    // Do the animation here. You could add meaningful argument types to control the animation
}
```

In XML, we can apply this using

```
    <TextView
        bind:shakeTrigger="@{vm.shakeTrigger}"/>
```

Then, in the viewModel, you can trigger the shake using Data Binding apis. One way using `BaseObservable` can be:

```
public class ConfigurationViewModel extends BaseObservable implements ViewModel {
    @Bindable
    public final Void shakeTrigger = null;

    public void shake() {
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.shakeTrigger);
    }
}
```

If you use RxJava, the trigger could be implemented from `rx.Observable`. You can checkout my library to use RxJava with Data Binding.
https://github.com/manas-chaudhari/android-mvvm

Comment: Shouldn't ViewModel class contain any Android elements like android.view.View for unit testing?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you don't and that's actually a good thing. In MVVM ViewModel is responsible for preparing and storing data for the view. So it gets the data from the model and makes it ready to be set on the view but it doesn't set the value, Setting the value and updating view states are responsibilities of the view itself, View in MVVM watches for changes in data and updates itself.

An example of this would be showing an empty list page when your list is empty. To do this in MVVM, you define a state for the view visibility in your ViewModel lets call it `emptyPageVisibility` and then update this value appropriately.

```
public class PlaylistDetailViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<Integer> emptyPageVisibility = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private void someMethodInYourViewModel(){
        emptyPageVisibility.setValue(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Then inside your view, you observe this and update the view when this data is changed like this

```
viewModel.getEmptyPageVisibility().observe(this, 
        visibility -> emptyPageView.setVisibility(visibility));
```